# Nested json objects in deep levels in retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I want to deserialize a json like this:

```
{
"software": {
  "info": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "نرم اقزار",
    "type": "complex"
  },

  "sub": {
    "windows": {
      "info": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "ویندوزی",
        "type": "complex"
      },
      "sub": {
        "photoshop": {
          "info": {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "فوتوشاپ",
            "type": "product"
          }
        },
        "word": {...}
       ,
        "matlab": {...}
      }
    }
  },
  "ios": {...},
  "linux": {...}
}
}
}
```

for doing this in `Retrofit` I programmed some models like this:

Root.java

```
public class Root {

    public Software software;
}
```

Software.java

```
public class Software {

   public Info info;
   public Sub sub;
}
```

Info.java

```
public class info {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String type;
}
```

Sub.java

```
public class sub {

    public Software software;
}
```

suppose all of getter and setters are in Classes.

my Interface :

ServicesAPI.java

```
public interface ServicesAPI {

@GET("services.php")
Call<Root> getSofwares();
```

}

and finally my MainActivity is this :

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    ServicesAPI servicesAPI = retrofit.create(ServicesAPI.class);

    Call<Root> call = servicesAPI.getSofwares();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Root>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Root> call, Response<Root> response) {
            //some codes
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Root> call, Throwable t) {
            //
        }
    });
```

when I build this code and run it, models just get the data of objects in level one and two. and the object in level three always give the `null`.

[image: this is the response]

Comment: can it possibly be caused by the recursive definition (nothing to do with being at the 3rd-level)?

Comment: exactly i want to be recursive. of course i tested with some different classes instead of `Software`. for example `SoftwareInLevelTwo`. but it was again `null`

Answer (score 0):

Class names should be written in upper case.

In your Case it would be

```
public class Root {
   private Software software;
   private Sub sub; 
   private Ios ios;
   // .... and so on
}
```

Since the name is sub, but the data are different, you may create another Model like

```
public class SubData { 
   SubInfo info; 

   class SubInfo {
      private int id;
      private String name;
      private String type;
   }
}
```

Your Sub class may look like that

```
 public class Sub {
    private Map<String, SubData> sub;
    private SubData windows; 
 }
```

You need to use a Map for that to let gson (de)serialize it for you. If those data are not known yet, you may want to use a custom deserializer and validate if the "key" is a JsonObject or a String.

Comment: in level two, the objects of `sub` might be infinite. i want to have all of objects. for example i can't make `windows` or `ios` as fields in my model. because these can be infinite fields.

Comment: In this case you will create a custom deserializer and "validae" if the Object is a JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

The given JSON looks to have inconsistent structure: `$.software.sub.windows`, but `$.software.ios` and `$.software.linux` lacking the intermediate `sub` property. Assuming that the latter two have to be probably nested directly into `$.software.sub` as the `windows` is (similarly to all of its descendants structure), you just don't need the `Sub` class: it cannot be that polymorphic as you're expecting it to be. The reason of why you're getting `null` is just that your JSON at path `$.software.sub.windows` (as well as `ios` and `linux` are) are not mapped properly: `Software.sub` expects your JSON document to have a field named `sub`. All you need is just modifying your `Software` class like this:

```java
final class Software {

    Info info;
    Map<String, Software> sub; // previously `public Sub sub;`

}
```

After that you can parse your JSON and easily traverse the parsed object:

```
final Root root = gson.fromJson(JSON, Root.class);
System.out.println(root.software.sub.get("windows").sub.get("photoshop").info.name);
```

The output:

> فوتوشاپ

Comment: Wrong assumptions about inconsistency? System.out? Direct Gson interaction? Broken output in a non-Unicode terminal for the Arabic script? Really, where did I get wrong? 